# Getting "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" when trying to load a background image

Tags: html, css

Working on a website at the moment and want a background image for the body. I keep getting a  `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. Heres my css file:

```
body
{
    background-image: url("C:\Users\jamie\Desktop\Work\Second Year\Web Design\CA2\Images\login.jpg");

}
```

Apologies if this question has been asked multiple times, but I've tried everything and have no idea whats going on, I ran developer mode and disabled cache on chrome, originally just had Images/login.jpg,I added quotes in the `url()` and didn't add quotes I've tried all sorts of different images in different files. Even downloaded firefox and tried it there but to no luck.

Comment: Kindly show us your directory / file structure.

Comment: Fortunately, people cannot grab random files from your computer just by figuring out the path were you store them. If you want to develop web sites you should install a local web server and then figure out how URLs work.

Comment: Try to put the image in the same directory as your css (or html - it isn't mentioned where you placed your style) file and simply link to it using `image.ext` - if that works, you know your path is simply incorrect. You can also try to replace it with `http://placehold.it/400x400` - if no image shows, either your style is incorrect or wrongly linked.

Comment: Okay I tried the `http://placehold.it/400x400` and it worked, I used the copy path button to my image file so I dont know why that wouldnt work.

Comment: In all likelihood, `C://` is not a valid protocol in the browser. Try to add the image in the same folder as your css and link it as simply the image. Also, if you hard link images to your harddrive like that you cannot move anything without it breaking, so it seems like a bad idea. Paths should be _relative_ to your source, using `../` to move up the folder structure.

Comment: I got it working, thanks for explaining it to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you put the login.jpg in the same folder as the css file
and change the css to

```
body
{
    background-image: url("login.jpg");

}
```

An absolute path is not correct, please use a relative one :)

Folder structure

```
MyCoolWebApp
|-> stylesheet.css
|-> login.jpg
```

if you want to access a file that is located in a parent folder of your stylesheet.css file, then use `url("../login.jpg");`

Comment: Just want to mention that absolute paths are not _always_ incorrect, but they can cause some unexpected issues.

Answer (score 0):

Go to inspect or Developer Tools in Chrome(where your local website is present).
Go to console and see the error.
In error, you can see the path (check carefully the path)

If there an error, type the correct path or copy-paste the path and try.